# Media Manager configuration issue with Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, media-manager

We have installed "SDL Web Connector 1.4 for Media Manager" (Media Manager ECL) on the Content Manager.

However, when clicking on the "SDL Media Manager" item in the tree in CME we are currently getting the following error:

> System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   No scope configured for the supplied AppliesTo:
>   http://XYZ.sdlmedia.com/WebServices/MediaManager2011.svc. Server stack
>   trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String
>   parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable1
>   basedOnSchema)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String
>   id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String
>   id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String
>   id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)    at
>   SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

All the configuration seems OK in `TridionSTS.xml` and ECL file.

```
<SigningCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="841e6a6961ea59787a98091417d61413a239d393" />
<!-- Update the thumbprint to match the certificate used to encrypt the token. The private part of the key must be installed and configured on the Media Manager instance -->
<EncryptingCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="4fee4adf78db41dc46a6ef556cba18659851fcfe" />
```

Comment: Add your configuration details in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check whether ECL and Media Manager service urls are entered using `https` in the TridionSTS.xml. Use `https` rather than `http` when you configure the URLs.